# HttpClient ThreadSafeClientConnManager throws "Connection reset"

Tags: java, httpclient, socketexception

I define HttpClient in 2 different ways:
1. Plain vanilla: client = new DefaultHttpClient();
2. Thread safe:

```
DefaultHttpClient getThreadSafeHttpClient() {
    HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
    params
            .setParameter(
                    "http.useragent",
                    "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 1.1; en-us;dream) AppleWebKit/525.10+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.0.4 Mobile Safari/523.12.2");
    HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
    HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, "UTF-8");
    final SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
    registry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
    registry.register(new Scheme("https", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 443));
    final ThreadSafeClientConnManager manager = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params,
            registry);
    return new DefaultHttpClient(manager, params);
}
```

Then I run same JUnit test for both client types (simple GET request). #1 always runs fine, #2 always fails with "java.net.SocketException: Connection reset". Debug/stacktrace output can be [seen here](http://www.nabble.com/file/p25157321/error.log) (fictitious site)

I never get a chance to do anything with entity object since error is thrown at client#execute call. What's I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aha! The reason was in defining HTTPS with wrong socket factory. It should be SSLSocketFactory

```
SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory();
sslSocketFactory.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.STRICT_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
registry.register(new Scheme("https", sslSocketFactory, 443));
```